# Convexity of open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. Intuitively, this is clear, but I would like to do it using the definition.

For simplicity I'll look at the $n=2$ case.

So suppose the ball has center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$, and let $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ be points inside the ball. So we have the inequalities $$\sqrt{(x_1-a)^2+(y_1-b)^2}<r$$$$\sqrt{(x_2-a)^2+(y_2-b)^2}<r$$ and we want to prove $$\sqrt{(tx_1+(1-t)x_2-a)^2+(tx_1+(1-t)x_2-b)^2}<r$$ where $t\in(0,1)$. How would this go?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off by avoiding direct calculations. Consider a ball $B(a,r)$, and suppose $x,y\in B$. Then $\lVert x-a\rVert,\lVert y-a\rVert<r$. Let $t\in (0,1)$. Then $$\lVert tx+(1-t) y-a\rVert=\lVert t(x-a)+(1-t) (y-a)\rVert$$

and use the triangle inequality.

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: [=D](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/yosemite-sam-with-guns.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is OK. Note that $f(x,y)= (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$ is a strictly convex function. By convexity, $f(tz_1+(1-t)z_2)<tf(z_1)+(1-t)f(z_2)<r^2$, where $z=(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

The norm $\|\cdot\|$ is convex. Hence the function $\eta(x) = \|x-x_0\|$ is also convex. It follows that the set $\eta^{-1} (-\infty, r) = B(x_0,r)$ is convex.